# How to put FK into another table using Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I have one login form like :

`Username: Ashish`

`Password: Pass`

`Contact no: 1234567890`

`State: Maharashtra`

Having two tables :

```
create table DGRegion
(DG_Regionno Int Identity (1,1) NOT Null constraint pk1 Primary Key,
 DG_Username varchar(50),
 DG_Password varchar(50), 
 DG_Contactno int ,
 DG_StateNo int References DGState(DG_stateno))


Create table DGState 
 (DG_stateno Int Identity (1,1) NOT Null constraint pk Primary Key ,
  DG_State varchar (50))
```

Now how can I create one stored procedure P which will enter values into `DGRegion` and `DGState` tables?

After click on submit I'm using asp.net.

Problem is: I can enter values into `DGRegion` table directly but how can I enter reference of state into table `DGState`?

Comment: Presumably the state `Maharashtra` might already exist and you only want to insert a new row if that is not the case?

Comment: A stored procedure can contain more than one statement so compile the logic you need and just wrap it in the procedure - a web search on 'create stored procedure' should be enough to get you going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.EnterLoginData(@Username VARCHAR(50), @Password VARCHAR(50),
                                    @ContactNo INT, @StateName VARCHAR(50)) 
AS BEGIN 
   DECLARE @StateID INT

   -- check if state already exists
   IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.DGState WHERE DG_State = @StateName)

      -- if it exists - retrieve the DG_StateNo
      SELECT @StateID = DG_StateNo
      FROM dbo.DGState 
      WHERE DG_State = @StateName

   ELSE BEGIN

      -- if it doesn't exists - insert new row 
      INSERT INTO dbo.DG_State(DG_State) VALUES(@StateName);

      -- get the newly inserted row's ID using SCOPE_IDENTITY()
      SELECT @StateID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
   END

   INSERT INTO 
       dbo.DGRegion(DG_Username, DG_Password, DG_ContactID, DG_StateNo)
   VALUES(@Username, @Password, @ContactNo, @StateID)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

In the sp:

- check if the state is in the state table
- if not, put it into the state table
- get the id (DG_stateno) of the state table, put in variable
- execute your insert

Comment: I agree on the approach but needs more specifics. 1 and 2 are quite easy to get wrong under conditions of concurrency especially in the absence of a unique constraint. 3 should explain how as well `OUTPUT`/`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the time to write full code example as something came up. If no one else answers I'll edit my answer with more details. :) For now, this should give OP an idea.